# Deploy Net Artifact from Nexus with GoCD

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, nexus, continuous-deployment, go-cd

I'm trying to use gocd to continuous delivery. My entrypoint is an artifact published on Nexus repository (It's a raw type). The artifact is is a .Net web project compressed as zip.

I've tried to use these GoCD plugins to download this .zip (Selecting Material Package in my pipeline) but without success.

- go-generic-artifactory-poller.jar
- go-maven-poller.jar
- gocd-nuget-poller-plugin-v1.0.3.jar

The problem is these plugins can't build the http path correctly. I think it's because this plugins are oriented to Java apps (group, artifact, version).